# Remove JSON object from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have a json array as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Name": {
              "query": "Nametest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Address": {
              "query": "NONE",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Site": {
              "query": "Adeswfvfv",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Phone": {
              "query": "5680728.00",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

So What i wanna do is if In json['query']['bool']['should'] if "query" is "NONE" then I wanna remove that json array and the new json will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Name": {
              "query": "Nametest",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Site": {
              "query": "Adeswfvfv",
              "fuzziness": 3,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Phone": {
              "query": "5680728.00",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried iterating over the json and used del(jsonarray) and pop(jsonarray) but nothing seeems to help out?

tried with python json library but failed

```
for e in q['query']['bool']['should']:
...     if "NONE" in str(e['match']):
...         del(e)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help.

```
import pprint 
d = {'query': {'bool': {'minimum_should_match': 2, 'should': [{'match': {'Name': {'query': 'Nametest', 'boost': 5, 'fuzziness': 3}}}, {'match': {'Address': {'query': 'NONE', 'boost': 4, 'fuzziness': 3}}}, {'match': {'Site': {'query': 'Adeswfvfv', 'boost': 4, 'fuzziness': 3}}}, {'match': {'Phone': {'query': '5680728.00', 'boost': 4, 'fuzziness': 2}}}], 'must': []}}}
d["query"]['bool']['should'] = [i for i in d["query"]['bool']['should'] if list(i['match'].items())[0][1]["query"] != 'NONE']
pprint.pprint(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'query': {'bool': {'minimum_should_match': 2,
                    'must': [],
                    'should': [{'match': {'Name': {'boost': 5,
                                                   'fuzziness': 3,
                                                   'query': 'Nametest'}}},
                               {'match': {'Site': {'boost': 4,
                                                   'fuzziness': 3,
                                                   'query': 'Adeswfvfv'}}},
                               {'match': {'Phone': {'boost': 4,
                                                    'fuzziness': 2,
                                                    'query': '5680728.00'}}}]}}}
```

Comment: I am on python 3.4 and caught this `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: try `d["query"]['bool']['should'] = [i for i in d["query"]['bool']['should'] if list(i['match'].items())[0][1]["query"] != 'NONE']`

Comment: Worked like charm, Its the first solution on stackoverflow to delete jsonobject in python, Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

I write this,but this seems complex

```
for p,c in  enumerate(json['query']['bool']['should']):
    if list(c["match"].values())[0]["query"] == "NONE":
        json['query']['bool']['should'].pop(p)
print(json)
```